# Why would a princess invite a plumber to a party?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

[image: Super Mario Run]

> Dear Mario,
>
> Why don't you join us at the castle for a party?
>
> I'll bake a cake!
>
> Yours truly, Peach

This is the first message I saw in *Super Mario Run* (Android).

While there's no reason why a princess can't fall for a plumber (classic rich-poor romance), it was supposed to happen at the end after Mario saved the princess with his heroism. But, it was weird that she wrote to a plumber in the beginning that way. How did this happen?

Note: This doesn't look like a normal friendship because of social differences. But, if it is indeed a friendship, again, how did this happen?

Comment: Well, considering they've been friends for over 30 years, it's not that odd that she would invite him to a party.

Comment: You're playing a game with carnivorous plants, walking mushrooms, militant turtles, and that's just off the top of my head, and your disbelief is in the social relationships?

Comment: Perhaps she urgently needed someone with a big wrench.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The continuity in the Mario franchise is [more than just a little screwy](https://www.mariowiki.com/Talk:List_of_chronological_references), however, it's generally accepted that the games do not take place in a vacuum.  Mario and Peach already know each other, and are most likely already in a relationship, at the beginning of Super Mario Run.

I'm pretty sure that in at least one Mario game, Bowser himself has made reference to his multiple attempts to "woo" Princess Peach.  I want to say Paper Mario?  Unfortunately Google is failing me as far as finding a reference for that quote.

Comment: Let's say, it's a sequel of previous games, are the characters on anti-aging charm?

Comment: I'd say it's more like they just don't consider aging in-universe.  Sort of like how Bart Simpson has been in grade school for like 30 odd years.

Comment: @Steve-O There's another explanation for that: https://youtu.be/zAFXmzC3LuA?feature=shared&t=191